# Should we merge [social-networks] and [social-media]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Should we merge [social-networks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-networks) (x 64) and [social-media](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) (x 127)?

They seem very similar in the ways that they are used to tag questions.

If merged, I suggest [social-media](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) as the canonical tag.

Comment: I concur with you and John.

Comment: Also aligned with the group on this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree. I think we should merge them and use [social-media](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) as the canonical tag. They are essentially the same thing, especially with the context of how they are used on this site.